# How can I get the username of the logged-in user in Django views.py

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and Django and struggling with the following issue:

I have a logged-in user that completes a form with 2 fields (urlA and urlB). These 2 fields, together with the timestamp and the users username should get stored in my PSQL database.

My current problem is that the urlA and urlB fields are pushed in the database, but the username stays empty or I get an error that self is not defined.

I have tried follwoing variations inside views.py:

```
forwardform.user = request.user.username 
User.objects.get(username=self.request.user) # -> gives error concering self
```

**views.py**

```
def forwardthis(request):
    forwardform = AddUrlForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and forwardform.is_valid():

        forwardform.user = request.user.username
        forwardform.save()
    query_results = forwards.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('forwardthis.html')
    context = {

        'forwardform': forwardform ,
        'query_results':query_results
    }

    #output = ', '.join([p.user for p in query_results])

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

**models.py**

```
class forwards(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    urlA = models.CharField(max_length = 254)
    urlB = models.CharField(max_length = 254)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddUrlForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = forwards
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ["user"]
```

Comment: `User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the form with `commit=False`, set the username, then save the instance.

```
if forwardform.is_valid():
    forward = forwardform.save(commit=False)
    forward.user = request.user.username
    forward.save()
```

Note you don't need to check `if request.methof == 'POST'`, since the form is only valid for post requests. For get requests the form is unbound therefore invalid.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, it worked out! only thing i changed was the following: `forward.user = request.user.username` in order to make it work like Sumeet suggested. thanks for your help

Comment: Good catch, fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
def forwardthis(request):
    forwardform = AddUrlForm(request.POST or None)
    if forwardform.is_valid():
        forwardform.save(commit=False)
        forwardform.user = request.user.username
        forwardform.save()
    ...
    ...
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

Comment: So this didn't worked out as the output "request.user.username" could not be saved directly into forwardform.user. I had to use a (what i assume is called a) variable forward, in order to save this one. but the `forwardform.user` made me think to change it into `forward.user` and it worked out